# How to generate XML file on the fly using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, rss

I am trying to fetch an extrenal webpage which includes a list of posts and regenerate it in RSS format. To analyze the HTML content of the target webpage I prefer using Jquery to extract the desired elements easily and this is what I did so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    success:function(data){
        analyzeHtml(data);
    }
})

function analyzeHtml(data){
    document.clear();
    document.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rss version="2.0"><channel><title>Example</title><description>Example Description</description><link>https://www.example.com/en/</link><generator>>PHP RSS</generator>')
    $(data).find("article").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".article-body-container").each(function(){
            var href=$(this).find("h3").find("a").attr("href");
            var title=$(this).find("h3").find("a").text();
            document.write("<item>");
            document.write("<guid>"+href+"</guid>");
            document.write("<link>"+href+"</link>");
            document.write("<title>"+title+"</title>");
            document.write("</item>");
        })
    });
    document.write("</channel></rss>");
    var myhtml=$("body").html();
    $("body").remove();
    $("html").append(myhtml);
}
```

Inspected output:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?-->
  <html>
   <head></head>
    <rss version="2.0">...</rss>
  </html>
```

I want to server the result as XML document so RSS readers can interact with this page. How can I celar those extra **Head** and **Html** tags using Jquery and append the result RSS in a clear window? (Do RSS readers handsahke with such document?)

Comment: I doubt an RSS reader will be able to execute the Javascript on a HTML page in order to receive the XML output. The only reliable way to make this work is to dissect the HTML on the server side and return the XML directly from your PHP.

Comment: Your issue is that `document.write` writes to ... well... the *document*: i.e. inside `<html>` tags.  Trying `$("html")[0].outerHTML = myhtml` to replace the html tag gives an error as, well... you need a document/html tag for your web page.